# Salesforce Developer edition asking for payments

Tags: developer-edition, enterprise

I have developed an application in Developer edition ,**Organization Edition    Developer Edition** ,but I have received mail from salesforce asking me to pay for **1 license of Service Cloud Lightning CRM - Enterprise Edition**. and its priced at  GBP 1,224.00 ,but when I navigate in salesforce CRM to Company Information it shows me that it is Developer edition. How could this happen ?

Comment: Does the org id in the Dev edition match that on the invoice? You find that on the company information details in Salesforce.

Comment: Can be a spam mail. Apart from that, I have once heard that salesforce asked to pay for full user license as the customer was using developer edition for production purpose and that breaks the MSA.

Comment: @DaveHumm thanks for staying in ,No the Invoice number nor the Account number had a match with my crm .

Comment: @PranayJaiswal the emails are generated from billing@emea.salesforce.com

Comment: @ALEX_RILEY - do you work for client organisations in which case your details might be down as the contact on their SF org?

Comment: What exact email address was the email from?